# Why does bash sometimes not start properly when i SSH into my raspberry pi from my computer (but works when SSH'ing from my phone)?

Tags: linux, networking, bash, ssh, raspberry-pi

Usually, I can ssh into my raspberry pi (running Raspbian 11) just fine. But sometimes, every few days, ssh will timeout. This will last about a day (independent of restarts of my computer), until when I will be able to ssh just fine again. At the same time, I can still ssh into the pi using my phone. To my interpretation, this rules out fundamental network issues; at least it's definitely possible to successfully connect to the pi.

From the output of `ssh -vvv pi@mypi` I understand that the connection is established successfully and regarding ssh, there is no problem, but then with starting the bash command, the connection becomes unresponsive and times out:

```
$ ssh -vvv pi@mypi
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
[...]
debug1: Connection established.
[...]
Authenticated to mpyi ([10.0.0.1]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions[...]
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00[...] want_reply 0
[...]
debug1: Remote: /home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SOME_ENV  
[...] # this is repeated a few times
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "de_DE.UTF-8"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env SOME_ENV
[...] # this is repeated a lot. ignored envs include TERM and GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
Timeout, server mypi not responding.
```

Using any command that does not need to be run in a terminal works. For example, when starting a second ssh session in parallel using `ssh pi@mypi sudo pstree`, this will output:

```
[...]
|-sshd-+-sshd---sshd---bash
|      `-sshd---sshd---sudo---pstree
[...]
```

Trying to get some information on the reason why bash is not responding, I tried to start bash with the `-x` option: `ssh -vvv pi@mypi bash -x`. The command prompt did was not shown, but this allowed interactive typing without timeouts (the SSH ServerAlive Packets are answered now as well). Executing `top` does not work though ("TERM environment variable not set.").

```
[...]
debug3: Ignored env SOME_ENV
debug1: Sending command: bash -x
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
echo test
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 12
test
+ echo test
debug2: channel 0: written 12 to efd 6
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
ps
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 5
+ ps
debug2: channel 0: written 5 to efd 6
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  310 ?        00:00:00 ps
  734 ?        00:00:01 systemd
  735 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
 1438 ?        00:21:08 screen
29175 ?        00:06:40 screen
32743 ?        00:00:00 sshd
32744 ?        00:00:00 bash
top
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 6
+ top
debug2: channel 0: written 6 to efd 6
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 35
TERM environment variable not set.
debug2: channel 0: written 35 to efd 6
# at this time, i hit Ctrl+C (on purpose)
# with bash -x on the server side, this is accepted as it should be
# (note: in previous setting, without -x, no input was accepted)
^Cdebug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 e[write]/0 fd 4/5/6 sock -1 cc -1 io 0x01/0x08)

Killed by signal 2.
```

Apparently, the terminal initialization process does not complete successfully. But only when using ssh from my computer, and only for a limited time of something like a day, happens every few days. I have no idea what could cause this or how to investigate further. Also, I have no explanation for why this happens only every so often and will then be back to normal after a day or so (and without the raspberry pi being restarted.)

Can someone help to investigate or explain the issue?

Comment: Signal 2 is interrupt from keyboard. Perhaps you are somehow doing CTRL-C during login.

Comment: @Bib when trying `ssh pi@mypi bash -x`, I hit Ctrl+C on purpose to see if it could end gracefully. When using `ssh pi@mypi`, hitting Ctrl+C (or anything else) does not have any effect. Edited log to clarify.